# Surface RT debugging

Tags: visual-studio-2012, windows-8, remote-debugging, windows-rt

I'm trying to debug a simple "Hello World" Windows 8 application on Surface RT but can't figure out how to connect it to Visual Studio 2012? I have Windows 8 installed on my VMWare machine and the [following instruction](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jasonz/archive/2012/06/12/what-you-need-to-know-about-developing-for-windows-on-arm-woa.aspx) but no result, the Surface is not visible for in Visual Studio. Is there any direct way to connect Surface to the PC by some type of cable?

Comment: Do you allow Remote Debugging in the Firewall?

Answer (score 0):

Check if your network is in the same domain.
next try opening the debugger in the surface and select options
in options you will find allow any computer to connect
under authentication
enable the option. Although it will warn you that it is not safe but will work.
authentication mode doesnot make a big difference if you are xonnecting locally . I dont have the links currently and answering from tab.

if these points do not work leave a comment. Ill look into the matter tomorrow when ill be on my system till them try. :)

Comment: i'm doing exactly in the way you described but no result. The both of them are on the same network, but the windows 8 pc is on vmware, maybe it is the problem ? maybe i need a real os ? and what about alternate way ? is there any other way to connect them ? cable or whatever else ?

Comment: I guess it will be better if you use the app package and install it on the surface. For crashing issues create a static class and keep a method inside that will create a file in local storage and log the exception details. And also a message box may be to check the same. Since it's a national holiday for us we are not able to access our machines today. So i wont like to go for a wild guess of how to connect to vs. Ill need to search to be frank the way i proposed might be a quick and small solution to ur testing :-)